# Python - Defining output of query to variables

Tags: sql, python-3.x, amazon-redshift

I am trying to call the output of SQL query to variables as below:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""select store_name,DATE_TRUNC('month',bill_date)as month,count(*) from sales""")
monthly_report = dwh_cur.fetchall()
```

The output of this file is as below:

```
store_name,month,count
store_a,jan,100
store_a,feb,200
store_a,mar,230
```

I am trying to pass months to a variable (var1) and count to another variable (var2)

Could anyone advice how could I define this accordingly. Thanks

Comment: could you include more code? where should these variables appear,  in place of the `fetchall()`?